# beamer: Footnote in columns Environment | Indention Too Short

Tags: beamer, footnotes, columns

- I often use the `columns` environment in `beamer` frames.
- When I have a long footnote within a `column` then the indention after the line break is very short.
- **Am I doing it right?**
- **How can I enlarge the indention?**

---

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text\footnote{Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text} Text.
        \item Text Text Text.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        %
        \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        %
    \end{columns}
%
Another Text\footnote{Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text} Outside The \texttt{columns} Environment.
%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Playing with your MWE, I discovered that columns doesn't really handle footnotes (doesn't force them to keep the column size and also causes the 
problem of your question)

This is the way I found that it works better:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text Text.\footnotemark[1]
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        %
        \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text\footnotemark[2]
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
        %
\footnotetext[1]{This is one: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
\footnotetext[2]{This is Two: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If you want separate footnote place for each column, this answer doesn't help you... And may be I can try for another way... But it is ok for my taste.

Output:

[image]

PS: may be we have to reduce a little bit from 0.5 (but I am not sure if columns use a inner or outer sep... so didn't do it yet)

**Edit** A fix but with not original indent of footnote:

I created the `footcolumn` to be used when footnotes are included instead of the original:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\let\oldfootnotetext\footnotetext
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\def\footnote#1{\footnotemark[1]\oldfootnotetext[1]{\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.9\textwidth}#1\end{minipage}}}}

\newenvironment{footcolumn}
{\begin{column}}{\end{column}\hspace{-0.5\textwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text TextText.\footnote{This is one: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text\footnote{This is two: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}

    \end{columns}
        %
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Test
        \item Text TextText.\footnote{This is one: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}
        %
        \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
        %
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

You can combine it with the original without problems (even as last column will work ok!). It is not perfect, because of the non indented start.. But Closer I think.

**Last Edit before remove previous:**

(Fixed some indent)

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\let\oldfootnotetext\footnotetext
\newdimen\myindent
\myindent=2mm
\newcounter{myfootnote}
\makeatletter
\def\footnote{\stepcounter{myfootnote}\xdef\themyfootnote{\arabic{myfootnote}}\@ifnextchar[{\readFootnoteNum}{\readFootnote}}
\def\readFootnoteNum[#1]{\footnotemark[#1]\xdef\themyfootnote{#1}\addtocounter{myfootnote}{-1}\readFootnote}
\def\readFootnote#1{\oldfootnotetext{\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.86\textwidth}\hspace{\myindent}$^{\themyfootnote}$#1\end{minipage}}}}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{footcolumn}
{\begin{column}}{\end{column}\hspace{\dimexpr-0.5\textwidth+\myindent}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text TextText.\footnote{This is one: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text\footnote{This is two: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}

    \end{columns}
        %
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Test
        \item Text TextText.\footnote[90]{This is one: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}
        %
        \begin{column}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
         \item Text Text Text.
        \item Text Text
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
        %
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}

    \begin{columns}[t]
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Test\footnote{Test here}
        \item Text TextText.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}
        %
        \begin{footcolumn}{.50\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text Text\footnote{This is one: Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text}
        \item Text Text
        \end{itemize}
        \end{footcolumn}

    \end{columns}
        %
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is definitely a workaround if there's no another solution closer to the MWE.

Comment: I found that there is a `ftnright.sty` package for such problems... But I am not in the mood to read about it right now... Take a look yourself

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, check my "fix"

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I can only upvote once. :)

Comment: Welcome @Dr.ManuelKuehner... If you need somechanges, like new numbers at every frame, it is easy to be done.. Also the margins and the indent can be adjusted easily. I suppose you can do your job for now...

Comment: I am just surprised that the default behavior is that sub-optimal. Maybe I am doing it wrong. I will wait a bit longer, maybe there are additional possibilities. Again, thanks and good night.

Comment: I was ready to sent you to fill a bug report but then I saw it is a known issue... I am used to work with mimipages than columns and it is an alternative way ... But also needs hacks for the footnotes.... Goodnight to you too...

Comment: Maybe you can link to the known issue. Would be helpful to me and maybe others. No hurry though. Over and out.

Comment: I mean that I found this documentation of the package `ftnright`: https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/required/tools/ftnright.pdf. This seems to exist because of known problems with footnotes in multiple columns... Just the existence of the package and some similar problems I found in this group made me to understand, that this is not exacltly a bug but there is possibly a reason (typography rule or something) to not allow footnotes in multiple columns, but to use the common footer instead. (Just a guess).

Answer (score 2):

If you are only concerned about the indention, then this can simply be cured by using `onlytextwidth`, otherwise also your two columns with each `.5\textwidth` are too big to fit on the frame without extending into the margin.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
%
\frametitle{Title of Frame}
    \begin{columns}[t,onlytextwidth]
        %
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Text Text\footnote{Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text} Text.
        \item Text Text Text.
        \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        %
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \end{column}
        %
    \end{columns}
%
Another Text\footnote{Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text Long Footnote Text} Outside The \texttt{columns} Environment.
%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In general I'd prefer the `\footnotemark`, `\footnotetext` solution from the begin of koleygr's answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Cannot test it right now. I will try it later.